# how to allow guests to upload image with wordpress default media uploader

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin where I need to make able guests to upload images , my media uploader successfully opened but it shows error while uploading photo .  My codes are below,

This is my php code

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts()
{

wp_enqueue_media();
wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/foldername/js/call_media_uploader.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');

}
```

and this is the jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){


var custom_uploader;


jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        jQuery('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);

    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();

});


});
```

Please tell me how can it possible to upload image using wordpress default media uploader .

Comment: Anyone? I also want to know how. I'm developing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not. WordPress does not support for guest to enable media uploader.